# SQL Server: live query statistics show a fast stored procedure time, but it takes almost a minute to return results

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure which has been variably quick and slow. I read about parameter sniffing and query plans and have been analyzing what differences in the query plan could cause this differential.

What I'm realizing is that it doesn't appear to be an optimization issue, parameter sniffing issue. I've used the estimated execution plan, actual execution plan and live query statistics to compare the plans in a variety of scenarios. While the return time in SMSS varies from subsecond to almost a minute, one thing is constant - all of the execution plans and live query statistics say the query is/was/should be fast. Live query statistics shows 0.074s on the latest run, yet the results took 52 seconds to return.

The flow goes like this:

- I execute the stored procedure from SMSS with Live Query Statistics enabled
- It whirs for a second generating the execution plan
- It displays the plan, then the status bar says "Executing Query... 0%"
- It spins for the next X seconds where X is between 5 and 52
- Then blip, the results pop up and the live query stats plan fills in instantaneously with a stated execution time at the green select node of between 0.074s and ~2s

Sometimes repeated runs of the same query go fast (which made me think, oh, it's loading the plan from the cache and able to execute quicker, but then I put OPTION(RECOMPILE) at the end of the stored procedure, which I read forces it to not use the plan cache), but other times it takes just as long. Sometimes when I change the input values it makes it go quicker and sometimes it doesn't. Again, the one constant - the plan/stats think it should be/is fast.

The stored procedure itself isn't too complicated, one select statement with some aggregating using windowing on a fairly small dataset and a couple of joins to other small tables - the max number of rows returned is about 90 on my test dataset. All of the critical columns have indices.

I really don't think it is actually a performance problem with the query itself, regardless of the differences in the plan, which I've seen a couple slight variations depending on the parameters passed in, the execution time estimates and live query stats are unanimously telling me - it's fast, sometimes so fast the live query stats don't even show any times underneath the nodes.

At some point of running it over and over again with different parameters it seems to settle on returning quickly, but only for a while. Then, usually just at the moment when I'm feeling like, "well whatever that was, it seems to be good now, moving on..." BAM right back to Slowsville.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information this is tough to diagnose. But, it sounds like you might have parameter sniffing happening.

https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/06/the-elephant-and-the-mouse-or-parameter-sniffing-in-sql-server/

Comment: Ya, that's what my research so far suggests - but the sniffing is supposed to affect the query plan that is generated.  Bad sniffing could result in a query plan which isn't optimal for other parameters, but I have seen several variations of the plan and they all say they're quick.  Plus, the part where it just spins on "executing query... 0%" doesn't seem to line up with the idea that it is just a poor plan - the plan comes back quick and says it has low estimated time, but then just spins, not actually executing the query.

Comment: This is really really weird... but maybe try running this... DBCC UPDATEUSAGE.

You may find this helpful: http://sequelserver.blogspot.com/2011/02/dbcc-updateusage-and-spupdatestats.html

Comment: I've got two internal back office SQL databases that require this as regular maintenance to avoid some whacky query plan behavior.